# Is it possible to prevent more than one device from syncing to Google Drive at a time?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I think the question itself covers my issue. 
I am using the Changes object to detect when there are modifications to files on a given user’s Drive account. My goal is to prevent conflicts by making sure that if a user is logged into my app on more than one device, there is no simultaneous syncing, and therefore, there will be no conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you to detect when the user is logged into your application. Would be to well log it some place in the database.    When ever a user logs in or does anything in your application save the time and the device name.

My issue will be how do you decide when the user is done.   If i am using your application on my phone then swap over to my desk top because i am done with my phone how are you going to know that and not just refuse me access on my desktop because i was just on my phone.

No Google does not offer anyway of you doing this from their end.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is pretty complicated. Clearly Google Drive is not perfect for the job, but it is free (I don't have to pay for resources) and easy to implement overall. The database idea sounds like a good idea, though. But I will not waste my time implementing it until I have all of the kinks figured out, such as the one you just described. Thanks.